# Change JSON to String

Tags: javascript, json

I don't have json package.And I create json object and want print it.Is there any way to do this by js native function?
Or I should write this function by myself?

P.S. I can't import any additional files.And I use Js in program not in browser. JSON is not defined.

Thanks!

Comment: JSON.stringify(jsonObj); https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add js script

```
<script src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/json2.js" />
```

alert json object

```
var obj = {
    a : 10,
    b : 20,
    c : {d: "foo", e: "bar"}
};
alert(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Comment: Script tag require closing tag + that url goes to a 404.

Comment: ... further the *raw* version is MIME type ('text/plain') – which will  exclude it from execution when strict MIME type checking is enabled. It is not compressed, not intended for direct linking, etc. Check out http://cdnjs.com/ or similar.